# Flutter image 8 edge crop

Tags: image, flutter, crop, scanning

I am working on image enhancement in flutter and need a 8 edged image cropper. All I could find in packages is a 4 edged cropper. I Will be grateful for any help

Comment: add more details.

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example or add more detailed code snippets on what you have tried. Thank you.